# Is There Any updated Webview Component in Java SE Swing?

Tags: java, webview

I want to make a java se software from where any one can browse websites. But There is no component like webview. TextPane is unable to show modern websites. Now I Am Using JxBrowser But It is very expensive. I Am Finding Webview Component For Java Similar to Android.

Comment: No there isn't. Browsers exist however, and they do a better job displaying HTML than your program ever could, so now you can come up with a better idea for your program!

Comment: No. I don't want to use Jx Browser. Why Oracle is not providing webview component??

Comment: Probably because it's irrelevant in a desktop environment. You can open the default browser with `Desktop.open();` and that's a lot better.

Comment: No desktop.open() just on default browser. So How to make a updated web browser in Java??

Comment: Why would you bother? It will look and work poorly, and using a ready made component for it is the same as if you did nothing. What are you hoping to get from this?

Comment: You Mean, I Have To write code for my own chromium framework browser like jxbrowser?? how can i do this?? any documentation from sun java??

Comment: I don't think you should be writing anything. I'm not clear whether you have a legitimate need for a webview component (hard to come up with a real reason), or if you're just playing around wanting to create your own "browser".

Comment: Its for my project. What should I do now??

Comment: Why do you need it for your project? What is your project about?

Comment: Ok I Have Got It. Its Java Fx That Supports WebView.

Comment: There you go! Great!

Comment: This is absolutely typical for StackOverflow in the last few years. Somebody asks a completely valid software development question and six trolls thoughtlessly debunk it. Meanwhile, people who actually want to know the same thing as the original poster have to wade through reams of officious nonsense to find the answer. Never, never ask *why* the poster wants to do what they want to do ... how incredibly arrogant to assume they don't know what they want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I Have Got It. Its Java Fx That Supports WebView

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavaFX {

    /* Create a JFrame with a JButton and a JFXPanel containing the WebView. */
    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on Swing thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FX");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null); // do the layout manually

        final JButton jButton = new JButton("Button");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

        frame.add(jButton);
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        jButton.setSize(new Dimension(200, 27));
        fxPanel.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        fxPanel.setLocation(new Point(0, 27));

        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 327));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { // this will run initFX as JavaFX-Thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    /* Creates a WebView and fires up google.com */
    private static void initFX(final JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

        WebView webView = new WebView();

        group.getChildren().add(webView);
        webView.setMinSize(300, 300);
        webView.setMaxSize(300, 300);

            // Obtain the webEngine to navigate
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com/");
    }

    /* Start application */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```